mupdf c api how to get image and path pdfobjects from every pdf page
In mupdf-1.24.2 c api,
I can only find these apis to get images position:
ref = pdf_new_indirect(ctx, doc, num, 0);
if (isimage(ref))
fz_empty_store(ctx);

But I can not find any apis to get pdf_objects from specific page; there is not any image objects in struct fz_page.
Is there any equivalent pdfium apis below in mupdf?
int cout = FPDFPage_CountObjects(page);
FPDF_PAGEOBJECT obj = FPDFPage_GetObject(page, i);
int type = FPDFPageObj_GetType(obj);
if (type == FPDF_PAGEOBJ_IMAGE) {
    float left, top, right, bottom;
    int ret_flag = FPDFPageObj_GetBounds(obj, &left, &bottom, &right, &top);
}

